# Change wso2 role names for LDAP

Tags: wso2, wso2-iot

I have setup WSO2 EMM with a Read-only LDAP as the user store..

I have gotten the user authentication to work, and if I create roles like subscriber, store or store-admin in the LDAP, that works as well..

But I would like to change the names of the roles, as they are a little too generic.. how do I that??

For the admin role, it can be done in: wso2emm-2.0.1/repository/conf/user-mgt.xml, by changing the:

admin

to something else... but I can't find this for the other roles...

Thanks

Comment: Hmmm.. The roles only works for the "admin" user... not for anyone else..